# How do you delete an entire bucket in riak 2.0 using curl?

Tags: riak

My buckets do not use Riak 2 object types, and I could not figure much from [the 2.0 documentation](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/references/http/#Bucket-related-Operations)

Answer (score 2):

A bucket doesn't really exist.  It is just a namespace that contains behaviors and settings to use when reading or storing keys.  You can reset the bucket to default settings, but in order to remove the data you would need to delete each key.

You could use the `$bucket` index to get a list of the keys, and you could probably write a map reduce job that would delete all of the keys in a certain bucket.  However, either of  those options would be about as heavy on the cluster as a key listing.

Comment: Yes I know a bucket is just a namespace. Should I assume no wildcards are allowed in the api then? I am not sure how to fiddle the new typed api, for my buckets having been migrated to 2.0.

Comment: No, as far as I know wildcards are not allowed and the only way to operate on more than one key is with map reduce.

Comment: Wildcards aren't a go over the API from what I see. I also found nothing related to bucket deletion. It seems it just isn't a thing - you can clear the properties with `curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:11098/buckets/sets/props` for example, but it still shows up in `/riak1/bin/riak-admin bucket-type list`